# boost / outputting to a file

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, stream

Can i output some text to a file using solely boost libraries?

The code i have (official documentation):

```
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> buf("log.txt");
    std::ostream                     out(&buf);
    // out writes to log.txt
    out << "abc";
}
```

Is there another way? (i dont want to use std streams). Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you not want to use std streams? What do you have against them?

Comment: Im trying to get familiar with boost. Im really a beginner and the documentation misleads me sometimes

Comment: Boost can partly be seen as an extension to the std library - actually many boost projects finally become part of the standard (like the smart pointers). So why should an extension provide something that is already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io::stream_buffer` is derived from `std::basic_streambuf`, so you can use native `basic_streambuf` public methods, or you can use `boost::filesystem` streams, but all of such classes are derived from `std::` classes.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#File-streams

Answer (score 7):

Input and output in a C++ program can be done in four ways:

1. Using C++ I/O streams. This is the recommended way. Even if using Boost I/O streams, it's all using the standard I/O streams behind the scene, and using the stream operators `<<` and `>>`.
2. The C `FILE` API: `fopen`, `fprintf`/`fwrite`/`fgets`/`fread`/etc. I think there are Boost I/O streams that handle `FILE`, but then you are still using the stream operators `<<` and `>>`.
3. On Windows, use of the POSIX subsystem file descriptors. I think these can also be used for Boost I/O streams.
4. Native file handling. On POSIX systems (e.g. Linux, BSD, OSX) this is the same as 3 above, on Windows see e.g. [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Boost I/O streams isn't supposed to be a stand-alone API, instead it is using one of the above I/O systems to simplify some things for the programmer.